# Error NetworkOnMainThreadException Consuming Restful Webservice using Android Client 4.0

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask

i have problem regarding my android client.

I have a script that consume a restful webservice and determine user authentication here's my code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;  
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class RestLogin {

private static String URL = "http://REST Webservice here?";
private static final String tag = "Logcat tag: ";


public static Boolean Auth(String username,String password)
{
    String result = "";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
    //adding parameter to request to determine user authentication
    request.addHeader("username",username);
    request.addHeader("password",password);
    //taking handler to get execution status
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try
    {
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
    }

        catch (ClientProtocolException cpe)
        {
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
        {
            iae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException npe)
        {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    Log.i(tag,result);
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(result);        
}
```

}

First, when i build the code, it shows error NetworkOnMainThreadException on my logcat status. Then, i find that since google android honeycomb, i can't directly using this method. So i need to add AsyncTask<>, here's the code

```
public class RestLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

private static String URL = "http://Restful webservice here?";
private static final String tag = "Logcat tag: ";

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    //TO DO Auto Generated Method
    return null;
}
```

now i'm stuck, how i can call the Auth() method using AsyncTask?

thanks in advance.

okay, UPDATE: this is new syntax

```
public class RestLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private static String URL = "http://REST Webservice here?";
private static final String tag = "Logcat tag: ";

private String usname, psswrd;
public RestLogin(String username, String password){
    usname = username;
    psswrd = password;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){          
    super.onPreExecute();
} 

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Boolean stat = Auth(usname,psswrd);
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
  {     
            super.onPostExecute(result);
  } 

public static Boolean Auth(String username,String password)
{
    String result = "";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
    //adding parameter to request to determine user authentication
    request.addHeader("username",username);
    request.addHeader("password",password);
    //taking handler to get execution status
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try
    {
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
    }

        catch (ClientProtocolException cpe)
        {
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
        {
            iae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException npe)
        {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    Log.i(tag,result);
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(result);        
}
```

}

Comment: Put your Auth Method in AsyncTask doInBackground(). You can Use asyncTask class As the inner class of your Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this:

```
public class RestLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private static String URL = "http://Restful webservice here?";  
private static final String tag = "Logcat tag: ";

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

       String username = params[0]; //username
       String password = params[1]; //password

       //now call Auth
       return Auth(username,password);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

       super.onPostExecute(result);

       if(result){

            //successful login. Display a Toast or take the user to next screen by using intent.
       }
       else {

           //Display Authentication failed error message.

       }
  }

  public Boolean Auth(String username,String password)
  {

        // your logic.

  }

}
```

> AsyncTask can be invoked by the following code.

```
  new RestLogin().execute(username,password);
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Go through some examples about AsyncTask for better understanding.

Comment: thanks for your answer. where i place the syntax :   new RestLogin().execute(username,password); ? 

activity on my another file?

Comment: in your activity class. you might be having a Login button right? write that in Login.setOnClickListener(){

Answer (score 0):

NetworkOnmainthreadException occurs because your are running network related operation on the main UI Thread. You should be using a **Asynctask** for this.

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

You can use a asycntask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            new TheTask(username,password).execute();
      }
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
   String username,pwd;
   public TheTask(String uname, String password)
   {
     username=uname;
     pwd=password;      
   }
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {           super.onPreExecute();
            //display progressdialog.
  } 

   protected void doInBackground(Void ...params)
  {  
        //rest web service. do not update ui here
        boolean somevalue= Auth(username, pwd);
        return null;
  } 

   protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
  {     
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //dismiss progressdialog.
            //update ui
  } 

 }
```

Comment: yes, i just add Asynctask, but now i'm stuck since the method Auth() is used by another file. how i can combine asynctask and the Auth() method?

Comment: i din't understand the complete scenario. Do you want to access the data returned by rest web service in another activity

Comment: here's the logic, i have 2 different class. First the login class which i place all the Activity. Second, LoginRest class which a class that gateway between client and webservice. The LoginRest class is shown above, this class is responsible for consuming and authenticate the user

Comment: you can use constructor to pass value and then use it in doInBackground(). Check the edit

Comment: @randytan you mean to say you need to call Auth() from both activities each time with a set of username and password. If thats the case create asynctask as a sepearate class in your package and pass the parameter to the constructor with username and password.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, i just updated the syntax. Now i just need to place the constructor, but how i can get the boolean value from authentication method? (true or false)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27484/discussion-between-randytan-and-raghunandan)